# The amount of current needed to accelerate for specific speed

Tags: electrostatics, magnetostatics

In the magnetic gun a conducting rod is placed on a two rails connected to a voltage source, so that a current can flow in the rod. Magnetic field $\vec{B}$  is applied perpendicular to the rail-rod plane.
 The rod length is $d$ and the mass is $m$ , the raillength is $l$ . What should be the current through the rod in order to accelerate the rod up to the velocity  $v$?

So I had no problem to analyze the problem, I understood how to solve it except to one part,

when I want to find the $|\vec{F}_{magnetic}|$ I did $$d\vec{F}=Id\vec{l}x\vec{B}\Longrightarrow\quad|\vec{F}|=\int d\vec{F}=IdB$$

but in the solution they got $$|\vec{F}|=\alpha IdB$$ I not understand where this $\alpha$ came from? I guess it is a constant but how exactly do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, a rail gun is connected to a very large charged capacitor.  When the circuit is closed, the capacitor discharges rapidly putting a very large pulse of current down one rail, through the rod, and back on  the other rail. Since the magnetic field strength depends on the length of rail which is carrying current, the field will different for each position of the rod.  The current will also be decreasing as a function of time as the capacitor looses charge.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your meaning, you say that the $\alpha$ is  responsible for the direction of the force?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was thinking of a changing current and B field.  It would appear that in your problem they have greatly simplified the situation.  I can only guess that the α is the fraction of the rod which lies between the rails. Or, their F may be the resultant after considering the effect of friction.